# Compiler doesn't infer template literal type when in function of another type

Tags: typescript, types, compiler-errors

For the following code, I'm using the arithmetic operation types written in [Ryan Dabler's Medium post](https://medium.com/itnext/implementing-arithmetic-within-typescripts-type-system-a1ef140a6f6f).

The following snippet produces a compiler error

```
// Test interface using the Add<A, B> type
interface Foo<Sum extends number> {
  increment(): Add<Sum, 1>;
  incrementString(): `${Add<Sum, 1>}`;
  /*                    ~~~~~~~~~~~
  Type 'Length<[...BuildTuple<Sum, []>, any]>' is not assignable to type 'string | number | bigint | boolean | null | undefined'.
  Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string | number | bigint | boolean | null | undefined'.(2322) */
  sumParam(param: `${Add<Sum, 1>}`): void;
  /*                 ~~~~~~~~~~~ Same error */
}
```

> Type 'Length<[...BuildTuple<Sum, []>, any]>' is not assignable to type 'string | number | bigint | boolean | null | undefined'.
> Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string | number | bigint | boolean | null | undefined'.(2322)

Why am I getting this error? From what I can understand, the compiler can resolve `Add<Sum, 1>` but not `` `${Add<Sum, 1>}` `` when in a function inside an `interface` (or `type`, for that matter).

Here are some other tests with unexpected results, the code above preceding.

```
// Testing types
type One = Add<0, 1> // 1
type OneString = `${Add<0, 1>}` // "1" - The compiler doesn't report an error. Why does it work now but not before?

// Testing with object
// I can declare all the functions even though there was an error before
const bar: Foo<0> = {
  increment: () => 1,
  incrementString: () => '1',
  sumParam: (param: '1') => {},
}

// Testing the functions
// They all run with the expected result even though there was an error before
const baz = bar.increment() // 1 
const qux = bar.incrementString() // "1"
const quux = bar.sumParam('1'); // void
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-PNgADAAkSyXQ9Xw32R43M1gqgACsRCJR-TgX5Rj2eLyvQGubwXUBzmgYQFBufZbnzQtq2QVJYEZRAAHkHFhJdSivUBdDyRDQBQ+A9xEXxYVPc9WRaDD-2vI8sLAAAiPI6NAPxQAAOWgDpUAoVBQH9Jw8AtRRQygsACyyWCIhQUBoDYAAreALS0GwGCyUA2GITY+wHUpxQnTcGGnHdNnncZRjyYFJwM7dZ0I6tjNDUzQB4PIeFBXR2NAGw3BeXZuG43j+IU7IFGEyUH0oZ8zS-XiPyizZnJ4ByxnHfY3LADyvJwHyeL86AeL4xwBOC4TIJ0USYOIlBEFIZQDMkaAVKUhrVPUgAvWF1NQSwtxnLwTOwpqVKLABHZRHA64huqs3rd33Xx+voxjmNAABRQqgsUUFsyaWtoGUHxIFrbhEDCQhIU4-ygVIPL4EG1TRrGiauvCyLX39BLQyuWjgNAhRlrWorNo6S4mBQPaDqOkhTvO3KeKum6tCAA) is the full code in TS playground. I tested it there and on my machine.

Comment: What is the specific question here? What, specifically, is unexpected in your other tests? (All I see is "expected"  in the comments, not "unexpected").  To resolve the errors inside `Foo`, you need to tell the compiler that `Add` will definitely produce a number no matter what, since it's not smart enough to just look at the definition of `Add` and see that this is true for generic inputs.  You can just write `number & Add...` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mq0zQN) and it should work.  But I don't know if that's what you're looking for or what other problems you might have.

Comment: Your hypothesis was correct, the compiler needed orientation with `number & Add<ArgsCount, 1>`. I updated the question (*with an actual question*) and the comments to reflect my confusion. If you want to respond to the question, Feel free, I'll mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TypeScript type checker doesn't have the advantage of human intelligence or the ability to look at the names of utility types as a hint to what they are doing.  Given

```
type Add<A extends number, B extends number> =
    Length<[...BuildTuple<A>, ...BuildTuple<B>]>;
```

when you write, say, `Add<2, 3>`, the compiler just goes ahead and evaluates it, producing the numeric [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `5`.  But if you write `Add<Sum, 1>` where `Sum` is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `number`, then the compiler doesn't know what to do with it.  It can't directly evaluate it, since it doesn't know what `Sum` is.  So it leaves it unevaluated and essentially opaque.

It also can't look at `Add<Sum, 1>` and say, "well, given the definition of `Add`, and the definition of `BuildTuple`, and the definition of `Length`, I know that whatever `Add<Sum, 1>` is, it will be assignable to `number`." That would require  higher order reasoning abilities possibly aided by the number-suggestive names `Add` and `Length`.  It just doesn't know. And therefore, if you put `Add<Sum, 1>` in a type position that is required to extend `number` (or `string | number | bigint | boolean | null | undefined`), the compiler will complain because it cannot be sure that it works.

The easiest way to proceed in cases like this, where you know that a type `X` is assignable to a type `Y` but the compiler doesn't, is to replace `X` with something like `X & Y` (the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types)) or `Extract<X, Y>` (the [`Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union)).  The compiler knows that `X & Y` is assignable to both `X` and `Y`, and if you know that `X` is assignable to `Y`, then `X & Y` is equivalent to just `X`.  Concretely:

```
interface Foo<Sum extends number> {
    increment(): Add<Sum, 1>;
    incrementString(): `${number & Add<Sum, 1>}`; // okay
    sumParam(param: `${number & Add<Sum, 1>}`): void; // okay
}
```

This fixes the error because it sidesteps the issue.  Now the compiler doesn't have to know that `Add<Sum, 1>` is a `number`, because whatever `Add<Sum, 1>` is, the type `number & Add<Sum, 1>` is definitely a `number`.  As long as we are correct in our assumption that `Add<Sum, 1>` will be a `number` of some kind, the additional `number &` will have no effect on the types that are eventually evaluated.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBUAsHsGcFNQBdICd6KQTwA71qAIbqgBmq0AtqAEpaEB2oAIoQEYA28qA5AdniKoAlikrwkwgMYEAsvAAmwgK7VikqVwBQIUJCRIcsAFwhxS1QDopVYKIbwAHkjuUcXcQ0kMA5gFpiUUhxDT8AdyDhBj8BfCkRHCRYGNx4P1gsWCR4SgCARnhSPIAWAAZCADZSKq1Y0AAZeF8UAB5wUCdshgUCRiwAbQBdAD5QAF4tUCmIDucmntAAb1AuZshjUCjSbgbQAF9QAH5djYcAN24Abi1a1NAAIWVhDgVwZXd4FvrZroWGVTY3AANDNOvNegwBoNxqAhqMJtNQXNugRlqsfCgNt8Dsd2htHs9Xu8uF8Qf1LBTwCC+iNrrdBABBBQKFoMn7g0D-SiA1Ag+7slGcgHceGTaaNNYtckUgkvN4fVnDEEUyyyokK+7DWk3OoAZWUbCQqEIUiQrIFf2FvIeFoIXJ5osRavlJIZozBgullgAFFsdgBVACUyplTzlxM+msGYqmxwlGMgLX9wxjoFO8AuqDpOjA4HwSE2Xm4pBNiGUsCiPmQkEQTJZDL5o1iWii2VQJakiAAYtBoC19dQPZbuSKlqmovEck0kN7Axs6-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)